# Abusing the strlen output

Tags: disassembly, c++, c, exploit, strings

My question is related to the `strlen` function from the C and C++.

I am reversing a program, that reads a byte data from allocated memory and sends to the `strlen` directly. To be completely honest this data is the hash value, so bytes could vary from 00 to FF.

I have found out that I can abuse this function with zero bytes to make `strlen` outputting less value than it should (as an example the string is 10 bytes long, but `strlen` output is 6).

Is there any way to abuse the function with any byte data inputted to `strlen` to output a bigger value(lets say 14)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the input is not 0-terminated. If that's the case, `strlen` will happily continue counting bytes until it finds one, moving out of the input's bounds. It then depends on how clean the memory is where the input is allocated.

Comment: Thank you, it looks very logical. Also, do you know anything about the cases when strlen negative return happens? Or should I better create another question for it?

Comment: Well `man strlen` says that signature is `size_t strlen(const char *s);`. `size_t` is unsigned so it should not return negative values @MatthewDarens It could have been casted to a signed value.